# 301 redirect old wordpress urls to new cakephp urls

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having some troubles redirecting my old sites blog posts from wordpress to the new cakephp formatted urls

I have 13 posts so it's not that many, I am trying to manually add them to the .htaccess file but they are not redirecting when you try to access them.

Her is an example of what I am trying

```
Redirect 301 /blog.php?freedom-church-chosen-experience /blog/post/10e-freedom-church-chosen-experience
```

There was some weird ajax stuff going on so that's why the ? in the previous url. But when I try to go to the old blog post url, it's not forwarding to the new one. We deleted the old site and pushed up the new cakephp site so those pages do not exist.

I have also added this to the app/.htaccess file as per an article I found here

http://www.davidtan.org/cakephp-tutorial-htaccess-redirect-301-rules-tips/

But I've tried a few different things and I can't get it to redirect.

Comment: What is the exact old URL's that you are trying to redirect and do the new URL's have a corresponding post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot match `QUERY_STRING` using `RewriteRule`. Just use this rule on top of your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(freedom-church-chosen-experience) [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog\.php$ /blog/post/10e-%1? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: I tried adding that to my root .htaccess file and it still doesn't work, but I saw that you use (^|&) to I changed that to ? instead of & and I got a 500 error on every page I tried to go to.

Comment: You cannot add `?` there. Rule has to be exactly as I wrote. Make sure this is first rule below `RewriteEngine` line. Also tell your exact full URL that didn't redirect?

Comment: Yeah it's the first one below the rewriteengine the full url I'm trying to redirect is this
http://chosenwomensconference.com/blog.php?freedom-church-chosen-experience
to this
http://chosenwomensconference.com/blog/post/10e-freedom-church-chosen-experience